# Issue with custome moduel installation in Sulu Admin

Tags: symfony, url-rewriting, sulu

I have integrated the Example module in my Sulu-standard installation. The code I used for the example module is from following repository :

https://github.com/sulu/ExampleNewsBundle

And the steps I followed for integration are from this

http://blog.sulu.io/how-to-develop-a-bundle-in-the-sulu-admin-1

After the installation I am getting this error while loading the JS for the module :

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://beauty_dev.com/en/bundles/examplenews/js/main.js?v=develop" 
Error: Script error for: /bundles/examplenews/js/main.js http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);
Error: Script error for: /bundles/examplenews/js/main.js http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);
```

After some research I found that 404 error was due to locale(en) appended in the URL.

Is it possible to remove the locale from the URL?

Any reference will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a new bundle you have to reinstall the assets using the following command:

```
app/console assets:install --symlink
```

Symfony doesn't do that automatically, so you have to execute this line, in order for the files to be copied to the `web` directory. You could also check if the accessed file is available in the `web` directory, which should be the case after executing the above command.

Regarding the language: You see that because Sulu tries to redirect to the default language if the current URL leads to a 404 and doesn't contain a language.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used the command but still same issue. Its specifically calling the **/en/bundles/examplenews**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the files in the `web/bundles/examplenews` folder exists and you can access from the browser? When the files exists and the webserver returns them correctly the `/de` will not be prepended.